# var = input("Press any key to continue") - Why does this not work?

Tags: python, input, osx-snow-leopard

I wrote a small text adventure in Python 3.2.2 and sent the .py file to a friend who is using a mac.

He ran the code after downloading the latest python for snow leopard and it ran alright until the line in the code: var = input("press any key to continue"). After that it just stayed at that line not producing any errors or doing much of anything, except that nothing happened when he typed anything. The characters he typed showed up at the prompt, but the program never moved forward.

I then froze the program using cx_freeze and sent it to my sister who is running windows xp (as am I) and she had the same problem. The game loaded up fine until that line.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They are probably using python 2.x, and need to press the return key. `input` expects a *line* of input, not a single character. The `input` function fundamentally changed between 2.x and 3.x, and the behavior  you see is consistent with python 2.x.

For background on the change in behavior, see [PEP 3111](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/)

Comment: I just realised. Wow, feel like a nutter now. Thanks.

Comment: To elaborate: `input()` only proceeds once it gets an entire line of input, i.e. by pressing the return key. If you want to get one character at a time, you need to do that another way.

Comment: on python 2.7.2 pressing just enter on an input produces a: "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" is that behavior any different in python 3k?

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! Python 2 `input()` and Python 3 `input()` are different beasts.

Comment: @Li-aung Yip: you are correct. I somehow missed the part where the original code mentioned python 3.2.2. I've changed my answer to better reflect what is probably happening for this user and his friends.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. As everyone else I send the code to seems to be using an older python version (2.x) than the version I wrote the code on (3.x), how would I go about prompting the user for an action before the code proceeds?